# Datatables with Meteor using Collections Join

Tags: mongodb, join, meteor, datatables

I want to display the data in a tabular fashion, Data will be fetched using the joins of collection from Mongo DB , I have some experience in Datatables that I have used in my previous projects

I have been trying with lots of Meteor stuff to accomplish this.

**What I tried and What is the result:**

I am using loftsteinn:datatables-bootstrap3 (https://github.com/oskarszoon/meteor-datatables-bootstrap3/) I am trying to display the data using joining of two collections, for Joining of collections I am using : https://atmospherejs.com/reywood/publish-composite.

The Issue : as the data gets fetched and the page gets rendered with the table it shows 0 records, but after a few seconds rows get populated and datatable gets filled but still shows 0 records.

To Counter this issue I have to set timeout for few seconds and then it shows correctly.

Is there any better way, as I feel that in case the data gets increased, I may face issues again.

***Possible Solutions with Other Packages?***

Is anybody has expirience in Joining of Collections and displaying correctly in the tabular format with Pagination, Sorting and Search?

I would Appriciate any help in this.

**CODE:**

***TEMPLATE***

```
    <template name="testdatatable">


    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable">
        <thead>
           <tr>
          <th>Todos Name</th>
          <th>List Name</th>
        </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

        {{#each todos}}
            <tr>
            <td>{{name}}</td>
                <td>{{lists.name}}</td>
        </tr>
            {{/each}}


        </tbody>
        </table>

    {{else}}
    <div class="loading">{{>spinner}}</div>
    {{/if}}



    </template>
```

***TEMPLATE HELPER***

```
Template.testdatatable.helpers({

    todos: function() {
        console.log(Todos.find());
    return Todos.find();
    },

    lists: function() {
    return Lists.findOne(this.listId);
    }

  });
```

***PUBLISH COMPOSITE using ( reywood:publish-composite )***

```
    Meteor.publishComposite('tabular_Todos', {
        find: function () {
          return Todos.find();
        },
        children: [
          {
        find: function(todos) {
        return Lists.find({_id: todos.listId });
        }
          }
        ]

    });
```

***ROUTING USING (iron Router)***

```
Router.route('/testdatatable', {
    name: 'testdatatable',
    template: 'testdatatable',
    onAfterAction: function(){
    calltestdatatable();
    },

    subscriptions: function(){  
        return Meteor.subscribe('tabular_Todos');
    }

});
```

***OTHER FUNCTIONS***

ON RENDERED

```
Template.testdatatable.onRendered(function(){

    setTimeout(calldatatable, 2000);

});
```

SETTING A TIMEOUT TO DELAY THE DATATABLE

```
function calltestdatatable(){

setTimeout(calldatatable, 2000);

}
```

DATATABLE INITIALISATION

```
function calldatatable(){
$('#myTable').DataTable();
}
```

---

**DATABASE**

***todos Collection***

[image: todos Collection]

***lists Collection***

[image: lists Collection]

Thanks and Best Regards,
Manu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my route that fixes the problem :

```
Router.route('testdatatable', {
  path: '/testdatatable',
  name: 'testdatatable',
  template: 'testdatatable',
  waitOn: function() {
    return [
      Meteor.subscribe('tabular_Todos')
    ];
  },
  subscriptions: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('tabular_Todos');
  }
});
```

and template

```
Template.testdatatable.onRendered(function(){
   $('#myTable').dataTable();
});
```

(as I used the --example todos, I had to change {{name}} as {{text}} to display the todo text)
[image]

Search, pagination, sorting works fine with [meteor add lc3t35:datatables-bootstrap3](https://github.com/lc3t35/meteor-datatables-bootstrap3) !

Comment: Hi Laurent, Thanks for your efforts, I will check this and will soon update, Let me check if this solution works for me.

Comment: I tested it it seems to be working fine, I hope it will also work properly with more collection joins

Comment: Super ! Nice gift for X-Mas and finishing the end of the year with a success ;) Please modify your title as [Solved] and link my answer. Happy new year !

Comment: Sure Laurent, A very Happy New Year to you as well :), Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question.
your data needs to come into `minimongo` first, then client side will be able to render those data. As a workaround you can use `loading` animation. a quick solution would be using `sacha:spin` package. and your Blaze code will be something similar to this.

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
   // load your view
{{else}}
<div class="loading">{{>spinner}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

your second problem is that ,db gets filled but table shows nothing except row skeleton. It's most probably because you have either problems with `helper` function or in the `Blaze` view. As you've not posted any code, it's hard to identify problem.

And to other questions: there are quite good numbers of packages for pagination and search. checkout `atmosphere`. you'll find some popular packages like `pages` and `easy-search`. you need to decide which suits for your project.

Comment: Thanks Kawsar, I have done some initial updates to my code using the template subscription ready condition, but I don't think it is working properly, I will get back on this soon and confirm if it helped me or not. I will post my code then.

Comment: Hi Kawsar and All, I have updated my post above and provided with the code and database screenshots. Could you please check and see what can be done to resolve this.

Comment: it's difficult to find out the problem here, knock me at `faysal@yahoo.com`

Comment: Kawsar & Manu, imho after trying most of the existing packages, datatables is the best to manage tables (sic!), search, sort and paginate. That's why I released the bootstrap'd datatables package (which was forked by oskarszoon/meteor-datatables-bootstrap3 from lc3t35/meteor-datatables-bootstrap3 because I forgot to update the datatables to 1.10.3) now it's updated to 1.10.10 ;) and you can use it with any bootstrap3 package such as ian:bootstrap-3 :)